# Merge two radial shapes with clean topology

Tags: modeling, topology

I am working on a joint which look like this. I would like to join the parts in a spherical fashion with the faces that I indicated with green marks. This type of problem keeps coming up and I don't know how to deal with it while keeping a decent topology. Is there a fit-for-all kind of solution for this?

[image]

I use Blender 3.5, here is my blend file as well.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First thing remove these faces (including the inner faces that should not be here):

[image]

Select these 6x2 edges on each part and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > *Bridge Edge Loops*:

[image]

Tweak the parameters in the *Operator Box* (*Number of Cuts* > 2, *Smoothness* > 0.6):

[image]

Do the same for the outer faces:

[image]

Fill the holes:

[image]